# Which smartfone OS/vendor is the safes when it comes to exploits?

Tags: exploit, android, smartphone

If I understand correctly, when an exploit for Android is found I have to manually patch my system because even though Google fixes the bug, vendors like Samsung, Huawei don't recompile their systems after every change of Android core.

So what is the best way to protect myself from exploits?
Here are the options I can think of:

- choose a smartphone for which there's an open-source system that's often updated - like CyanogenMod, and flash that system to the phone
- forget Android and get smartphone with Ubuntu Phone
- perhaps there are some vendors that update their systems very often? maybe OnePlus?

Answers regarding iPhones and Windows Phone are welcome for completion sake but I'm not interested neither in Microsoft nor Apple products. Only open source stuff.

Comment: Hi there - this type of question doesn't really work here. The one Dave linked to does list out things you could consider from an importance perspective but this is broad, opinion based, and changes frequently. You have ruled out Apple, but currently they should be much more secure than android.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answers given in this earlier question might perhaps be of some help to you?

[Mobile Phone security - help finding security/privacy review/discussion](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/94558/mobile-phone-security-help-finding-security-privacy-review-discussion)

In addition to Ubuntu Phone, as stated in an answer to that question, there is also Sailfish OS, but, unfortunately, both have a very small market share, and hence few apps, and hence a small market share..